# Camel creating too many tcp connections (over 15000) in TIME_WAIT status to connect ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, message-queue

I am using Apache Camel(with Spring) and ActiveMQ in project. Here are the settings related to JMS/ActiveMQ:

**Camel version: activemq-camel-5.15.3.jar** (all ActiveMQ related jars)

**ActiveMQ version : 5.15.0**

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<bean id="defaultActiveMQRedeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
</bean>

<util:list id="redeliveryPolicyEntries">
    <bean id="activeMQRedeliveryPolicy1" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
        <property name="queue" value="inbox"></property>
    </bean>
</util:list>

<bean id="amqRedeliveryPolicyMap"
    class="org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.RedeliveryPolicyMap">
    <property name="defaultEntry" ref="defaultActiveMQRedeliveryPolicy"></property>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicyEntries" ref="redeliveryPolicyEntries"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="amqPrefetchPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="20" />
    <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="40" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory">
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${jmsConnectionFactory.brokerURL}"  />
     <property name="userName" value="admin" /> 
     <property name="password" value="admin" /> 
    <property name="prefetchPolicy" ref="amqPrefetchPolicy" />
    <property name="redeliveryPolicyMap" ref="amqRedeliveryPolicyMap" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="15" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="30" />
    <property name="asyncConsumer" value="false" />
    <property name="cacheLevelName"  value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />
</bean>

<!-- this bean actually represents a jms component to be used in our camel-integration 
    setup.make endpoints by using name(id) of this bean. -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
    <property name="transacted" value="false" />
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
        </bean>
    </property>         
</bean>
```

As you see I am using **PooledConnectionFactory** so I am expecting a fixed no of connections to connect with ActiveMQ. **But unexpectedly I see a large no of TCP connections being opened in TIME_WAIT even when my application is idle and no messages are being produced/consumed at time.** I confirmed this situation with infra team that confirmed all the **Operating System** level configuration are fine.

Here I tried debugging the *doReceiveAndExecute* method in **AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer**- *sessionToUse* is not null, *consumerToUse* is also not null and code flows through *receiveMessage*(line number 304).I could not find the problem in debug trace as attached in debug screenshots:

[image: AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer debug]

and

[image: JmsDestinationAccessor debug]

and my actual problem

[image: My actual problem]

Is it a problem with MessageListenerContainer or with ConnectionFactory?? Am I missing some configuration which would prevent this from happening or is this an existing issue? If so is there a workaround?

Comment: Are these consumer or producer connections? According to the [documentation of PooledConnectionFactory](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/jms/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.html) it allows the creation of consumers but won't pool them actually.

Comment: These are consumer connections. I assume that is OK as it should cache the TCP connections at least. Also as you can see I have given            
 <property name="cacheLevelName"  value="CACHE_CONSUMER" /> in jmsConfiguration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just spotted in your configuration that you configured the `jmsConnectionFactory` (not the pooled factory) in your transaction manager. Not sure if this could raise the issue because the pooled factory is simply not used.

```
<property name="transactionManager">
    <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: Please note this line - "even when my application is idle and no messages are being produced/consumed at time". So actually these are not producers as system is just restarted and in idle state.In Screenshots I have mentioned that even in idle situation background thread is working and calling -DefaultMessageListenerContainer.

Comment: I just spotted you use the (not pooled) connection factory in your tx manager. edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I tested with pooledConnectionFactory and now it works fine. Now I realized why earlier version of my project had no such problem. I changed that accidentally in recent.